# Merge SQL Tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have two tables, which have the same columns except for 1. So for example:

```
Table1 (column names): Student | Course | Exam1 | Exam2
Table2 (column names): Student | Course | Exam3 | FinalExam
```

I would like to combine these two tables to get:

```
Table: Student | Course | Exam1 | Exam2 | FinalExam
```

I have something along the following:

```
Select
    student,
    course,
    Exam1, 
    Exam2
From Table1

Select
    student,
    course,
    Exam3, 
    FinalExam
From Table2


Select
    student,
    course,
    Coalesce( t1.Exam1, 0) as Exam1 
    Coalesce( t1.Exam2, 0) as Exam2
    Coalesce( t2.Exam3, 0) as Exam3
    Coalesce( t2.FinalExam, 0) as FinalExam
From Table1 t1, Table2 t2
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently/succinctly using an inner join?

Comment: Do you need the cartesian product created? Because t1, t2 will produce a cartesian product instead of a join. You can join them by student and course based on your explanation.

Comment: Have you the same `Student, Course` combination in both tables?

Comment: Need more information.  Is the student and course guaranteed to be in both tables?  If not, how do you want that treated?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is a cartesian product which will have n*n rows.

Try this

```
Select
    student,
    course,
    Exam1,
    Exam2,
    Exam3,
    FinalExam,
From Table1 t1, Table2 t2
Where t1.student=t2.student
and t1.course=t2.course;
```

This query works on the arrumption that the students have appeared for the either exams 1 or 2 atleast AND either exams 3 or Final.
If there is a possible case of absent, then you need to use outer join.
Like the following example, but not limited to

```
Select
    student,
    course,
    Exam1,
    Exam2,
    Exam3,
    FinalExam,
From Table1 t1, Table2 t2
Where t1.student=t2.student(+)
and t1.course=t2.course(+);
```

Comment: Agreed. If we all understood the question it doesn't make sense to make a Cartesian product. +1

Comment: Please don't use the old-style implicit joins in the where clause. Use the modern explicit `JOIN` syntax - especially for outer joins. Oracle recommends to stop using the (proprietary) `(+)` operator.

Comment: Could you please post the source @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: It's [in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#i2054062): "*Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator*"

Comment: Thanks... Point noted

Comment: This is the solution I was using initially - I was trying to "merge" all of the rows, but I realized that this may not be so clean. In the end I used this as a subquery, and then summed all of the values I wanted combined in the final query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I *think*  you want based on some assumptions from your question.

```
 select isnull(t1.student, t2.student),  isnull(t1.course, t2.course),
    IsNull( t1.Exam1, 0) as Exam1 ,
    IsNull( t1.Exam2, 0) as Exam2,
    IsNull( t2.Exam3, 0) as Exam3,
IsNull( t2.FinalExam, 0) as FinalExam
From Table1 t1 
   full outer join  Table2 t2 
        on t1.student = t2.student 
            and t1.course = t2.course
```