# How to merge two tables according to time Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have following two tables "payment" and "Cancelpayment"
Here is my payment table

```
id          bookingId       userId      status      createdON   
1           120             120         1           2020-06-01 10:24:29
2           124             120         1           2020-06-03 18:25:22 
3           126             120         1           2020-06-06 22:21:33
4           128             121         1           2020-06-06 22:28:11
```

Here is my table "cancelpayment"

```
id          bookingId       userId      status      createdON
1           121             120         1           2020-06-02 10:11:14 
2           123             120         1           2020-06-03 13:14:28
```

I want to merge both table means i want get all record of user (userid=120) from both tables but according to createdON
means whether user record in "payment" table or "cancelpayment" should be showing Assending

I tried with following code but not working for me

```
SELECT bookingId as BookingId,status,createdON FROM cancelpayment WHERE userId='120' 
UNION 
SELECT bookingId as BookingId,status,createdON FROM payment WHERE userId='120'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge SQL Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836382/merge-sql-tables)

Comment: Please show us the expected output and also tell us why you expect it.

Comment: "I tried with following code but not working for me" What is not working fine?

Answer (score 2):

Add a computed column:

```
SELECT BookingId, status, createdON
FROM
(
    SELECT userId, bookingId AS BookingId, status, createdON, 1 AS src
    FROM payment
    WHERE userId = '120' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userId, bookingId, status, createdON, 2
    FROM cancelpayment
    WHERE userId = '120'
) t
ORDER BY
    userId,
    src;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY bookingId` rather ? There are no `userId` in the query (and the query is filtered with `userId = '120'`, so sorting by it makes no sense)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `**ORDER BY createdON ASC**` in your query like this:

```
SELECT bookingId as BookingId,status,createdON FROM cancelpayment WHERE userId='120'
UNION 
SELECT bookingId as BookingId,status,createdON FROM payment WHERE userId='120' 
ORDER BY createdON ASC
```

**MySQL Output:**

[image]